# How do I UV Unwrap Part of my Object?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv

I want to apply a texture to a section of my object, but I don't want anything showing up anywhere else on my object. When I select the part of my object that I want unwrapped and unwrap it, it also unwraps every other part of the object, but unwraps each face as a full square. The area selected unwraps just fine.

This seems to be fixed by scaling all the UV's I don't want down to 0, but is there another/better way?

Comment: you can use two materials one for each part

Comment: What version of Blender are you using? Selecting a face in Edit mode and unwrapping works for me.

Answer (score 10):

**This works in Blender 2.74**

---

Select your mesh, enter edit mode, and select only the faces that you want to unwrap. Now press <kbd>U</kbd> and select the type of unwrap you want to use:

[image: Example Gif]

Notice that when I select other faces, the only visible selection is a vertice on the lower left, while an unwrapped face becomes fully visible when selected in the viewport. Basically, Blender automatically unwraps the selected part of the mesh, and then sends all other vertices to `0, 0` as there is no coordinate information to display for them. However they do still display a color:

[image: Moving Verices]

---

What you can do is to assign a different material to the not unwrapped vertices so that you can control the color easily. Select all the unwrapped faces and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to invert the selection. Now go to the materials panel and make a new material, and press the *Assign* button:

[image: Assign Material Gif]

Comment: it is there ( see the left-bottom point ) it just put to (0,0), they are all unwrapped

Comment: I didn't say you have scaled it :P , but they are unwrapped and all their points overlap at (0,0) and they will have a color from this texture

Comment: paint other corners ( only the corners ) and they will turn into pure white

Comment: So it must take the average of the corners only. I wonder if that is how an image is sampled normally in Blender (when not unwrapped)?

Comment: **Major revision underway**

Comment: The dots in the lower left part, what determined the color of the mesh the left corner dots have

Comment: Still works in Blender 3.0 :)

Answer (score 1):

you can select all faces in edit mode and in uv mode select the ones you want to unwrap and HIDE the rest, then press U or do whatever uv operation you need

Answer (score 0):

I usually unwraps faces in groups. Not like unwrap all the faces and adjust them. And for the first time I just had this issue as well. (on Blender 2.77)

### The Issue:

One face selected:
[image]

CTRL+U to UV unwrap. Notice that nothing is on UV Maps on right panel:
[image]

But, it unwraps every single face on that object:
[image]

### My Solution:

Click the + button to create a UV Map (Red Arrow on Right Panel):
[image]

Then, CTRL+U to UV unwrap. This unwraps only the selected face:
[image]